# System tray icons grouping

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, notification-area

Is it possible to manage or group tray icons somehow ?
Let's say I have multiple apps running in background:
steam,
docker,
discord,
google sync.
They are doing its job while remaining in notification area.
Can i group them in folders (background apps for example) or something like that ?
No, I don't want to hide them.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Gently point your mouse onto an icon and move it left or right.  I do this routinely to arrange icons so the main ones are left-most.

Comment: drag and drop them anywhere you want.

Comment: Good point but not really what i want.

Comment: Given they are in the system tray and you do not want them hidden, then I think the above fits.  I use a single height taskbar, and if you use double height you can also adjust up and down.